# a few image layers that can be dragged and dropped

Tags: java, android

i want to create an app which includes a few layer images that can be dragged and dropped in android studio. any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set onTouch Listeners on all the images and handle the drag in onTouch by changing the layout params of your image view.

And to hide the view just check if your x an y goes beyond the dimensions of the  screen and change the visibility of the view.

The Code is **just a sample**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        final int X = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
        int action = motionEvent.getActionMasked();


        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            Log.i(TAG, "Action down!");
        }

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Action move!");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -550;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
}
```